# Use variables to set in style with javaScript

Tags: javascript, css

```
function Scale(){
    X = innerWidth / 1024;
    Y = innerHeight / 768;

    Z = document.getElementById("IFM");
    Z.style.transform = "scale(X, Y)";
}
```

I have a problem with this code. I couldn't use variables in scale!
What can I do with this problem?

Comment: How would you think are string contents distinguished from variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript has no inline string variables. All you can do is concatenate strings:

```
Z.style.transform = "scale("+X+", "+Y+")";
```

The numbers will be implicitly converted to strings.

You might as well use some custom [`sprintf`-like](https://stackoverflow.com/q/610406/1048572) format- or replace-methods, but usually concatenation with `+` is simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You either build the string with *concats* / *plus* or use `String.prototype.replace`.

```
Z.style.transform = "scale(" + X + "," + Y + ")";
```

or with a helper like

```
String.prototype.sFormat = function _simpleFormat( map ) {
    var myString    = this.toString(),
        args        = map instanceof Array ? map : Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments );

    while( ~myString.indexOf( '%r' ) ) {
        myString = myString.replace( '%r', args.shift() );
    }

    return myString;
};
```

.. and then go like

```
Z.style.transform = "scale(%r, %r)".sFormat(X,Y);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change that line to:

```
Z.style.transform = "scale(" + X +", "+ Y + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way "scale(" +X+ "," +Y+ ")";